# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ImageView

Tags: android

I have a error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" how fix it? (sorry for this bad log format, i don't write many code text)

my activity_main.xml , error this

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCosmonaut"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background_cosmonaut"/>
```

LogCat

```
  05-05 16:04:10.313    2475-2475/com.vlad.genius.game E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vlad.genius.game/com.vlad.genius.game.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                ...
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                ...
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                ...


    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
                    at com.vlad.genius.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you try searching for the error? there are tons of questions reguarding this error

Comment: Where is your java code? Most likely your Java code is going to be the culprit behind an out of memory error, not your xml.

Comment: So, a) what device are you using, and b) what resolution is the image in the `ImageView`?

Comment: I'm guessing background_cosmonaut is the problem. Is it really a valid image?

Comment: background_cosmonaut has resolution 1080x1920 and size 374.47Kb

Comment: So, according to the link @m.hashemian posted in their answer, that file alone is going to use 8 Megs of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the bitmap you have assigned to your image view is too large to be loaded in your app space. You have to find an alternative way.

Generally for large bitmaps, it's not a good idea to assign them in the XML. Inflation of the XML happens in the UI thread and loading a large bitmap, even if it does not cause OOM, will cause occasional ANR.

I HIGHLY suggest you to read [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), it gives you very valuable lessons how to deal with images in Android in the right way.